# Not able to type underscore in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and use ubuntu-desktop. For some reason I am unable to type an underscore character anywhere on the Linux server. I am using a standard US English keyboard.
Thanks

Comment: What **does** happen when you hit that key? Do you get nothing at all, the wrong character on the screen, a weird noise?

Comment: This ^^^ Please [edit] the question and update it accordingly.

Comment: Hello....When I pressed Shift + underscore key, nothing was appearing and the cursor was not moving to the right indicating a character was being typed. Not sure what changed or updated, but I rebooted several times yesterday, and today the problem seems to have fixed. I am now able to type an underscore. Very strange. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: I'd be concerned that it's a hardware problem and the fact that it showed up during a software upgrade was coincidental. At least give the keyboard a good cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

To enter a character by its code point, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> , then type the four-character code and press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en#compose) can also work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Did something change in Ubuntu, since I was able to type Shift key and underscore key previous to this upgrade? Sorry, what four-character codes are you referring to?

Comment: @twolsey The unicode for ASCII underscore is 005F. (Those are zeroes, not capital "o")

Comment: And no, nothing that could impact the keyboard use changed.

Comment: Hello....When I pressed Shift + underscore key, nothing was appearing and the cursor was not moving to the right indicating a character was being typed. Not sure what changed or updated, but I rebooted several times yesterday, and today the problem seems to have fixed. I am now able to type an underscore. Very strange. Thanks to all for your help.